# How to have multiple rows of items on a UIToolbar?

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm trying for what is done in Apple's "Maps" app when "Directions" is selected:

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

Does anyone know how to have multiple rows of UIBarButtonItems? I haven't found the answer anywhere. I can add items in a single row to the UIToolbar as follows:

```
    NSArray *newItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: settingsButton, textFieldStartItem, goButton, nil];
    toolBar.items = newItems;
```

But that just puts all of the items in the same row.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard toolbar, but a custom view. You can't do this using the basic UI classes, you'll have to write your own. A simple thing to try is to create a large toolbar and add fields as standard subviews on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view.

```
- (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView
```